# Running a jar file on other Windows versions

Tags: java, jar

I've written a code that is supposed to be exporting a set of windows registry keys. I've successfully written the code and was able to also send the results of executing the code as a jar file to my email. However, while testing the jar file ( I've included the piece of code in the build.xml from the java website that will allow me to run the jar file out of the  **dist**  folder) I was able to get the desired results on my machine because I wrote the code on a windows 8.1 machine. While testing it on another machine ( with Windows 8 and Windows 7 professional ) I was not able to execute the code and the error I was getting was as follows :

**"Java Virtual Machine Launcher, A Java Exception has occurred."**

I used to get that error message when I did not include the code in the build.xml page to allow the jar file to run out of the dist folder, but now I'm getting it when I'm executing the jar file on different machines other than my own

Running it from the command prompt this is what i got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: smc_1/SMC_1
W1 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @JimGarrison I will include the piece of code corresponding to my problem .

Comment: Do you have an exception and stack trace to go along with your error?

Comment: @sherb no there is no error, it's just when I double click on the jar file it gives me that error. In terms of code, I ran the program before creating the jar file and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: @Sara, can you try running the jar from the command line? For example, `java -jar MyJarFile.jar` That should produce an exception and stack trace.

Comment: @sherb I just did and it's giving me "Exception in the thread main java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersion Error" Ill add the rest in the question

Comment: @Sara, you'll need to `cd` to the directory your jar file is in before you run `java -jar MyJarFile.jar`. Update the question with the error and stack trace once you get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sara, that error is a JVM mismatch error. I think you're trying to run a jar compiled for Java 8 on a system with Java 7 (or older) installed. Your options are (a) update the JVM to Java 8 or (b) recompile your application with the target set to 1.7 or whatever JVM you need to target, provided that your app doesn't include any Java 8-specific code. Oracle has some information on updating Java to the latest version here: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml

Comment: I thought so too, but I tried running it on another windows8 machine and it didnt work, how can i possibly fix that?

Comment: @Sara, I've updated my answer. Also, you can use `java -version` to determine what JVM release is installed.

Comment: so you're implying to update the available java version? I'll check the  link and let you know what comes about! Thanks.

Comment: I just checked the java version of the Windows 7 pro machine and it's the 1.7 so I think that's the problem and it's already uptodate.

Comment: @Sara, the update utility may not be enough; you may need to run the Java 8 installer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html