# Cannot compile jar for windows

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

I have coded a really nice application for me and my friends. I compiled it and created an executable jar. It works perfectly on my mac. However, when I shared the program with my friend who owns a windows computer, he couldn't open the file. I had similar problems with my other programs so this it's not about my code.

Comment: Does he have java installed? https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive about what "couldn't open the file" means.

Comment: yes he has java installed he has a message that pops and says : a java exception has occurred . That message pops when he opens the executable file .

Comment: removing more general tags, and those about osx which is working fine.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace from the exception that he sees? It will help to figure things out. Did you do any file operations from your code? It might not be performing those ops in a multiplatform away. We will need to figure out where the error is and check that part of your code to be able to help.

Comment: What command is your friend using to run your jar? (Just to follow up on the title of the question, you do not need to recompile the jar for windows. Jars themselves are runnable on any platform. The code may need to change to support the other OS'es however.)

Answer (score 0):

[Java by it's nature should be OS independent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861592/possible-to-run-jar-file-on-any-os)

with that said there's some pretty good reasons why you can't run a .jar file.

1. [The system doesn't have Java installed.](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml)
2. [The Jar file was compiled using an incompatible version compared to the system Java installation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692626/is-jdk-upward-or-backward-compatible/4692743#4692743)
3. [The jar file uses native libraries (JNI).](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html)
4. [The jar file isn't a native executable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable)

Comment: it's not the first one for sure. The second one doesn't seem likely either. I don't understand what the third one means. For the fourth one, can't I just distribute a jar file ?

Comment: Thank you for answering me in so little time :)

Comment: What version of Java did you compile with? What version is on their machine?

Comment: when I run it in console mode, it says it can't find the main class