# My application won't open for Mac OS users

Tags: java, macos

Recently, I have created my first public Java application, which opens a simple GUI. I have tested it on my Windows PC, but someone reported that the file does not open on their Mac OS. 
Since I do not have anything running a Mac OS to test it, I'd need your help to tell me if there are differences when building the JAR file...
Because for all the people with Windows, it does work. 
Is it something while building the JAR file? Or some part of the code would be different for Mac OS?
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Mac OS X? Do they have correct java version on their mac os x? Which version your app needs?

Comment: What is the specific error / output message when they run it on a mac?

Comment: Needs more details as to how it isn't opening. Most common reason is directory paths are forward slashes, not backslashes. If you have a shell script, make sure to use $n instead of %n, and escape out $ if used in command line.

Comment: Time to go to the apple store.... that's how they get you. ;-)

Comment: I wanna buy a mac book, but here in my country it is really expensive...

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are designed to run on any OS that has a JVM of a compatible version installed. Some jar files, however, may have be compiled from Java code that used OS-specific code (say talking to Windows registries), so testing it on other OS's is wise.

Original post by [Kathy Van Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115432/kathy-van-stone) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861592/possible-to-run-jar-file-on-any-os).

Answer (score 0):

It ended up it was a security error, fixed by them with tips from the Apple.com page ([here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11436?locale=en_US))
Thanks!